# php regex to match facebook pages, groups and usernames, but ignore links with query params

Tags: php, regex

I have these possible matches

```
https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=13046212397316299911&amp;ev=pageview&amp;noscript=1
https://www.facebook.com/pages/something
https://www.facebook.com/groups/something/
https://www.facebook.com/something
... random other non-facebook links
```

The last 3 are valid, but the first one I want to rule out using preg_match_all

Currently

I have this regex which includes all 4 of them, and for the first one, it matches on

```
https://www.facebook.com/tr
```

But I want to rule it out completely

This is my current regex

```
 $pattern = "/(?:(?:http|https):\/\/|)(?:www\.|)facebook\.[a-z.]+\/((pages|groups)\/|)[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{1,}/"
```

Also when it does match, $matches contains something inside both [0] and [1] and [2] which I don't know why it's happening. I just want a match or no match

Any help please?

```
    $links = [
        'https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=13046212397316299911&amp;ev=pageview&amp;noscript=1',
        'https://www.facebook.com/pages/something',
        'https://www.facebook.com/groups/something/',
        'https://www.facebook.com/something',
    ];

    $pattern = "/(?:(?:http|https):\/\/|)(?:www\.|)facebook\.[a-z.]+\/((pages|groups)\/|)[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{1,}/";

    foreach ($links as $link) {
        if ($matchesFound = preg_match($pattern, $link, $matches)) {
            if ($matchesFound) {
                d($matches);
            }
        }
    }

array (3) [
  0 => string (41) "https://www.facebook.com/groups/something"
  1 => string (7) "groups/"
  2 => string (6) "groups"
]
```

Comment: Try `^https?://www\.facebook\.com/(?:pages/|groups/)?\w+/?$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fsn6s1/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern you use 2 alternations where you have no value after the last `|`. The http or https part can be shortened to https? and that part including the `www.` does not have to be in a non capturing group `(?:`.

You could move the forward slash into the group to match pages or groups and make the group optional using a question mark. Then match an optional forward slash at the end.

If you use a different delimiter then `/` like `~` do don't have to escape the forward slashes.

Your regex might look like:

```
^https://www\.facebook\.[a-z.]+/(?:pages/|groups/)?[\w-]+/?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T8X2em/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/MOgm3)

For example:

```
$pattern = '~^https://www\.facebook\.[a-z.]+/(?:pages/|groups/)?[\w-]+/?$~';
```

If you want to match more but not the querystring params, you could match 1+ not a question mark or a whitespace char using a negated character class `[^?\s]+`.

```
^https://www\.facebook\.[a-z.]+/(?:pages/|groups/)?[^?\s]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QLJCHz/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/F2iQS)